# JSF 2.0 method invocation with argument from var of dataGrid

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I use primefaces with facelets and i have a quastion:

for example i have dataGrid and i want to call method of bean, that registered in faces-config, to include some dynamic content:

```
<p:dataGrid var="provider" value="#{paymentFormBean.providers}">
   <ui:include src="contentFactory.getSpecificForm('some attribute')"/>
</p:dataGrid>
```

How could i invoke getSpecificForm method with argument from var of dataGrid? Something like:

```
<p:dataGrid var="provider" value="#{paymentFormBean.providers}">
   <ui:include src="contentFactory.getSpecificForm(provider.formName)"/>
</p:dataGrid>
```

UPDATE: if i try to invoke method in actionListener of any component in dataGrid:

```
<p:commandLink update="details" actionListener="#{contentFactory.getSpecificForm(provider.formName)}" />
```

then attribute is passed corretly, but in ui:include the value is empty

Could anyone help me? 
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make `ContentFactory` a managed bean

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped // Or whatever
public class ContentFactory {

    public String getSpecificForm(String formName) {
        return null; // TODO: implement.
    }

}
```

so that you can use EL to invoke it

```
<ui:include src="#{contentFactory.getSpecificForm(provider.formName)}" />
```

---

**Update:** I forgot, `ui:include` inside an UI repeater doesn't work. Consider using `c:forEach` instead of `p:dataGrid`. You'll only have to apply/nest the desired components and/or HTML/CSS yourself inside the `c:forEach`.

```
<html xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core">
...

<c:forEach var="provider" items="#{paymentFormBean.providers}">
    <ui:include src="#{contentFactory.getSpecificForm(provider.formName)}" />
</c:forEach>
```

Comment: Yes, the method invokes but formName is empty and  provider.getFormName doesn't invokes. It seems like in <ui:include> provider var is not visible or empty or something like this.

Comment: Yes, that's work! Thank you! But why it doesn't work in UI repeater? What do you think is it bug or feature? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try [JBoss EL implementation](http://repository.jboss.org/maven2/org/jboss/el/jboss-el/)

In web.xml add the following context-param:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>org.jboss.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Comment: have you got the similar task and jboss EL implementation resolved it? Or it just 'try, but there is no assurance'? :) Because it is very useful feature and i hope that jsf EL implementation should be able to do it. It would be weird if it doesnt.

Comment: JBoss EL was previously used to enable passing method arguments in older servletcontainers before JSP 2.2/Servlet 3.0. But if you're already using a JSP 2.2/Servlet 3.0 container (Tomcat 7, Glassfish 3, JBoss AS 6, etc), then JBoss EL doesn't offer extra advantages.